# Undo adding disks to a RAID-Z Configuration

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, zfs, network-attached-storage, raidz

I've started running out of space on one of my data pool and decided to expand it by adding some extra disks. Below is what it looked like before extending:

```
        NAME                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    data                       ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0                 ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50041BF93A7d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50041FEBCFFd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50041FEBE1Bd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50041FEC223d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50041FECC0Bd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C500422BAF33d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Now after extending the pool I've got first set of drives in raidz1 and the second set using raidz2

```
        NAME                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    data                       ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0                 ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50041BF93A7d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50041FEBCFFd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50041FEBE1Bd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50041FEC223d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50041FECC0Bd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C500422BAF33d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-1                 ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50034245B57d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C500350A3847d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50042033AA7d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C500421FBD03d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C500422B9737d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C5005678B8BFd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

This is my mistake, no excuse. My question is how do I undo this operation so I can setup the drives again to have raidz1-0 and raidz1-1? Data is being written to the data pool only during the night as this is a backup pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've messed up... Sorry.

I'd love to see the output of `zpool history data`. But my guess is that you wanted to add more disk space, but instead, you added a group of 6 disks in a RAIDZ2 and set it to stripe with your RAIDZ1 set.

You should know that RAIDZ vdevs aren't expandable... the only way to "grow" the pool is by adding another vdev. You were trying to create something like RAID 5+0 and possibly mistyped?

Either way, there's no option to unstripe these two vdevs. Do you have the ability to send the data somewhere else, reformat and try again?

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid this is the case and moving data/recreating the pool is the only option here. Thanks for your input on this.